# Error Not enough storage is available to process this command. Click url from email workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a client side problem. and the client gets an email notification from the workflow task approval and there is a url link to a list and open editForm.aspx?...  when clicked on the url there is an error notification pop up as below.

> Something unexpected went wrong with this URL:
>
> "http://sitesharepoint/lists/AssetRequest/Editform....".Not enough storage is available to process this command.

please input for this matter

Comment: have you checked site storage metrics from site settings?

Comment: Hi Murad, I checked my storage metrics in subsite under 262.1Mb or 2.58% of parent. please suggest about this storage matrix.

Comment: Are they able to open edit form from the list?

Comment: and it can be the issue with the SharePoint server as well

Comment: they able open edit form from link url email, because i set edit form for approve side in form custom.